# Word for "a slight argument over different bets"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

### **Explanation:**

> I can't come up or think of a **noun** and **verb** that would
>   describe a **situation**, where 2 or more **people** made different **statements**
>   about some situation and both are **not sure** if their statement is
>   **correct**, but they **presume** that it is.

### **Example:**

> Two friends made 2 **different** statements about the **opening time** of
>   a store. One stated that it opens **at 9**, another - **at 8**.

### **Specifications:**

> They **did not**:
>
> - have a quarrel
> - make physical/monetary bets
>
> They just each **claimed** that their **memory** about the store's
>   opening hours is **correct**.

### Usage:

> **Verb:** "Me and John **_______** whether the store opens at 9 or 8 and he won."
>
> **Noun:** "Our **______** with John about the store's opening time was won by John."

### **Question:**

> How would you name **the situation (noun)** that they had and call **the
>   action (verb)** that they performed?

Comment: Four comments: 1. Do you have your "noun" and "verb" sentences the wrong way round? 2. I'd prefer "John and I" rather than "Me and John", I think. 3. But if there is no dispute or quarrel, what is there to **win**? That seems an odd choice of word. 4. Why do *disagreed* and *disagreement* or *differed* and *difference* not fit?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, you beat me by four seconds.

Comment: One issue is that you don't win a disagreement or difference, which is why I hesitate to offer it as a concrete answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach about second point of yours - I am not a native speaker, so I tend to make minor mistakes. Thanks for pointing out, good to know that! Besides, "differ" is a good one as well.

Comment: The first example (actually Verb but labeled Noun) can use *surmised*, 2nd one could be *assumption*. In both cases they indicate presumption of correctness without definite proof.

Comment: @Alok okay, now I notice the error. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: *debate*, *discussion*, *disagreement*, *argument*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the noun **disagreement** or the verb **(to) disagree**.

Comment: Great! I think that's the word I was looking for. I'll wait for other candidate suggestions and if none will fit better - will accept your answer. Thank you, @as4s4hetic !

Comment: @Eduard no worries :)